# SQL server - remove null values from query using STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to modify the below query to show only not null data. For example in the picture below result should cotain only record with id 1,6,7.

```
declare @datainizio as date='20210511'
declare @datafine as date='20210511'
declare @idTerminale as int=0

SELECT
      a.COGNOME
    , a.NOME
    , STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + md.VERSOO + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),md.DATAO,108)
          FROM TIMBRATURE md
          WHERE a.id = md.IDDIP and (DATAO >= @datainizio and DATAO < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @datafine)) and (0= @idTerminale OR md.IDTERMINALE=@idTerminale)
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') as tab2
FROM anagrafico a
ORDER BY COGNOME
```

[image]

Comment: Put the above in a CTE/subquery and then simply use `WHERE Tab2 IS NOT NULL`? If you're on SQL Server 2017+, then you can actually just use a `INNER JOIN` and `STRING_AGG` and the data will be filtered automatically.

Comment: @Larnu sadly i'm on sql server 2014... I can't see how to use subqueries in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, just use a CTE or subquery. The CTE method would be:

```sql
DECLARE @datainizio AS date = '20210511';
DECLARE @datafine AS date = '20210511';
DECLARE @idTerminale AS int = 0;
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT a.COGNOME,
           a.NOME,
           STUFF((SELECT ',' + md.VERSOO + CONVERT(varchar(5), md.DATAO, 108)
                  FROM dbo.TIMBRATURE md
                  WHERE a.id = md.IDDIP
                    AND (DATAO >= @datainizio AND DATAO < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @datafine))
                    AND (0 = @idTerminale OR md.IDTERMINALE = @idTerminale)
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') AS tab2
    FROM anagrafico a)
SELECT COGNOME,
       NOME,
       tab2
FROM CTE
WHERE tab2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY COGNOME;
```

I've also amended the `value` function to use `text()`, as it's less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter out the `NULL` values in a `WHERE` clause:

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + md.VERSOO + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), md.DATAO, 108)
       FROM TIMBRATURE md
       WHERE a.id = md.IDDIP AND
             md.DATAO >= @datainizio AND
             md.DATAO < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @datafine) AND
             (0 = @idTerminale OR md.IDTERMINALE = @idTerminale) AND
             md.VERSOO IS NOT NULL
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
             ), 1, 1, '') as tab2
```

Comment: I must have been unprecise, i want to filter for nulls on entire "tab2" result